# How to call onChangeText function when mapping it from array

Tags: react-native, higher-order-functions

I am using an **Array** to **map data** by using **higher order function map**. And I am also using **cutome component InputField** which is receiving props. but when I call the function it says.

> Failed prop type: The prop `onChangeText` is marked as required in
>   InputField. but its value is `undefined`.

So when I console.warn the email and password it shows empty.

***Here is my code***

**SignIn (Screen)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StatusBar, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";
import InputField from "../../components/InputField";

class SignIn extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    textInputData: [
      {
        inputType: "email",
        placeholder: "Enter Email",
        multiline: false,
        autoCorrect: false,
        autoFocus: true,
        onChangeText: this.handleEmailChange
      },
      {
        inputType: "password",
        placeholder: "Enter Password",
        multiline: false,
        autoCorrect: false,
        autoFocus: false,
        onChangeText: this.handlePasswordChange
      }
    ]
  };

  //handle email text input change
  handleEmailChange = email => {
    this.setState({ email: email });
  };

  //handle password text input change
  handlePasswordChange = password => {
    this.setState({ password: password });
  };

  replaceScreen = screen => {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate(screen);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor={"#455A64"} />
        {this.state.textInputData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <View key={index} style={styles.inputViewContainer}>
              <InputField
                inputType={item.inputType}
                placeholder={item.placeholder}
                multiline={item.multiline}
                autoCorrect={item.autoCorrect}
                autoFocus={item.autoFocus}
                onChangeText={item.onChangeText}
              />
            </View>
          );
        })}

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonContainerStyle}
          activeOpacity={0.7}
          onPress={() => {
            this.replaceScreen("HomeNavigation");
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>SignIn</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
          <Text>Don't have an account? </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={() => {
              this.replaceScreen("SignUp");
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.signUpTextStyle}>SignUp</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default SignIn;
```

**InputField (Custome Component)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";

class InputField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secureInput: !(
        props.inputType === "text" ||
        props.inputType === "email" ||
        props.inputType === "number"
      )
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {
      inputType,
      placeholder,
      multiline,
      autoCorrect,
      autoFocus,
      onChangeText
    } = this.props;
    const { secureInput } = this.state;

    return (
      <TextInput
        inputType={inputType}
        secureTextEntry={secureInput}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        multiline={multiline}
        autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        style={styles.textInputStyle}
      />
    );
  }
}

InputField.propTypes = {
  inputType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  multiline: PropTypes.bool,
  autoCorrect: PropTypes.bool,
  autoFocus: PropTypes.bool,
  onChangeText: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInputStyle: {
    color: "black",
    fontSize: 16
  }
});

export default InputField;
```

How to solve this. I am waiting for your solution. And please let me know if I am using the right way or not to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few hours, I solved the problem. I only changes the **onChangeText data in state** in **SignIn Screen**. No changes in custom component **InputField**. The problem was, I was calling the method wrongly from state.

**Before**

```
state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    textInputData: [
      {
        inputType: "email",
        placeholder: "Enter Email",
        multiline: false,
        autoCorrect: false,
        autoFocus: true,
        onChangeText: this.handleEmailChange
      },
      {
        inputType: "password",
        placeholder: "Enter Password",
        multiline: false,
        autoCorrect: false,
        autoFocus: false,
        onChangeText: this.handlePasswordChange
      }
    ]
  };
```

**After**

```
state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    textInputData: [
      {
        inputType: "email",
        placeholder: "Enter Email",
        multiline: true,
        autoCorrect: false,
        autoFocus: true,
        onChangeText: text => this.handleEmailChange(text)
      },
      {
        inputType: "password",
        placeholder: "Enter Password",
        multiline: false,
        autoCorrect: false,
        autoFocus: false,
        onChangeText: text => this.handlePasswordChange(text)
      }
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add onChangeText from props you have to use the default props in the mean time while props are loading so that can full-fill your requirement

```
InputField.defaultProps = {
   onChangeText: () => {}
}
```

Comment: inside InputField (Custome Component)

Comment: you can add this after proptypes

InputField.propTypes = {
  inputType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  multiline: PropTypes.bool,
  autoCorrect: PropTypes.bool,
  autoFocus: PropTypes.bool,
  onChangeText: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

Comment: Error is gone but when I tried to consol.warn() the email and password, it shows empty.

Comment: Here is the code

InputField.propTypes = {
  inputType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  multiline: PropTypes.bool,
  autoCorrect: PropTypes.bool,
  autoFocus: PropTypes.bool,
  onChangeText: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

InputField.defaultProps = {
  onChangeText: () => {}
};

Comment: Please check handle change function seems to be something wrong with that